# STM32 and SDCard: space management

Tags: stm32, interrupts, sd, dma

My task is to gather measurement from peripheries of STM32F4 on SDCard and I started reading about this. Could you double check if I'm correct:

- Single block memory on my SDCard is 512 bytes, so before I would write anything, I should gather 512 bytes of data (otherwise I will waste the rest of block).
- To do that, I need to write queue. I deceided to create DMA in fifo mode, to transfer from flash to SRAM, and in DMA interrupt use FatFS function to move it to SDCard.

And my second question, what would be the best option, when gathered data will trancend 512 bytes (ex. before loop execution there are 510 bytes of data and there comes new 10 bytes). Is DMA functionality provide itself or I should prevent it someway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, when you write less than 512 bytes, your FatFS (or almost any other) library will:

1. Read the block into RAM
2. Append your data to the existing one.
3. Erase the block on SD card.
4. Write the whole block from RAM.

And I'm obviously not mentioning the library reading any file descriptors or anything which will most likely also happen if you open the file every time you want to write to it as opposed to writing to one that's just opened once at the beginning.

As to the second question: It depends. 
If you configure the DMA to use just a 512 byte buffer 2 things can happen:

1. If the DMA is configured to use the buffer as a circular buffer, in your example it will write the 2 bytes at the end of the buffer and overwrite the first 8 bytes at the beginning of the buffer with the remaining bytes.
2. If you're not using it as a circular buffer, assuming that you configured it to trigger a "Transfer Complete" interrupt, it will be triggered right after the last (512th) byte is stored in the buffer. Now depending on the transmission speed of your source of data (whatever it is you've not mentioned) you have a limited time - you must reconfigure the DMA to use another buffer or if there's enough time, process your data before the next byte arrives.
   If you don't handle that Transfer Complete interrupt in short-enough time and new data arrives, all that new data will be lost and the DMA will trigger an Overrun interrupt (if enabled).